# Python - selectively add up values while iterating through dictionary of dictionaries

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, key-value

I have a following dictionary:

```
 result = {key:value}
 dict = {key1:{value1:value2}, key2:{value3:value4}, key3{value5:value6}, key4:{value7:value8}...}
```

I need to iterate through it and

```
if (value2+value3 == 3):
         result[key1] = key2
```

Any recommendations on how to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: is it really like this ? do you have dictionary with just one pair of key value as main dictionary values ?

Comment: I dont understand. Are you trying to always add the key and the value in each key of dict? Or are you trying to add the value of one to the key of the next?

Comment: Its really a shame that people don't take just a little more time to construct questions that allow the community to really engage. It wastes peoples time and the just adds more cruft to the flow of this site.

Comment: THat is unbelievable... is the aggression necessary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
my_dict = {key1:{value1:value2}, key2:{value3:value4}, key3{value5:value6}, key4:{value7:value8}...}
result = []
for key1 in my_dict:
    if sum(my_dict[key1].keys() + my_dict[key1].values())==3:
        result[key1] = my_dict[key1].keys()[0]
```

Hope this helps